# Using log4j, how I do logging to the Windows console?

Tags: java, console, log4j, logging

How I do to the logging go to the Windows console (that black thing, CMD, COMMAND)?
I'm trying with ConsoleAppender, but I don't if I doing it right.

```
private static ConsoleAppender appender = new ConsoleAppender(new PatternLayout());
private Logger database;

Log() {
    BasicConfigurator.configure();
    database = Logger.getLogger("DATABASE");
    database.addAppender(appender);
}
```

EDIT:
**first**: this code is a sample, it is bigger than this
**second**: on the console of Netbeans works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup all the appenders before logging information. Usually the setting up of log4j (including adding appenders) is done during startup of your application.

You should read the documentation [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) before trying anything more.

Comment: But the ConsoleAppender will give me the functionality to log to the console?

Comment: Yes, it will log to the console in which your application is running.

Comment: @Renato - it will work, but configuring the logging system like that (in code) is almost certainly wrong.  You should do it in the config files, so that the logging can be reconfigured without changing the code and recompiling.  That's what the documentation will tell you ... if you read it.

Comment: Yes, I take a look at documentation. This is for a simple start. I think I was making a mistake. Logs will only appear if I start the application from the commandline, right? If yes, it was my fault because I was starting direct from the icon on desktop. I can't test if is this because I got an NoClassDefFoundError, but this I resolve later. Someone can confirme if is this, the logs will only show up when I start the application from commandline?